# NGC Throwing Error Cannot find type definition file for 'rx/rx.all'

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I am trying to do some [updating to the flex-layout project](https://github.com/jrgleason/flex-layout/tree/UPGRADE). I noticed when it runs ngc

`./node_modules/.bin/ngc -p src/lib/tsconfig.json`

it gets...

`Error Cannot find type definition file for 'rx/rx.all'.`

As you can see I am importing the type and it sees to be a problem coming from Angular. Without downgrading "@types/rx", how can I fix this issue?

The linked branch should be UPGRADE, this has the package file changes to upgrade dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea what `ngc` is but since you're using Angular2 you're also using RxJS 5 which is only in the `rxjs` package.

The older RxJS 4 was moved to the `rx` package instead so I'm suspicious you're trying to import a wrong package.

Comment: This is for Type Definitions, so even if the RxJS library changed their namespace, @types/rx might still be diff (static Typescript types). I think it has to do mainly with the Typescript configuration (remove that declaration from the tsconfig)

Comment: So you're using both RxJS 4 and RxJS 5 in one project?

Comment: No I am using the RxJS 5 lib and the @types/RxJS and here we are talking about @types/RxJS which this does not apply to only the actual RXJS lib. The types lib is just static declarations for typing.

Comment: To be honest I have no idea what you're talking about. You're saying you're using RxJS 5 but at the same time you're using `rx/rx.all` and `@types/rx` from RxJS 4 so I don't understand what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

The answer for me was just deleting the line from the tsconfig